# Calculating random events in the future

Tags: probability

I feel as though I may have missed a clear solution but am asking anyway as I cannot see it.

Let's say I have a a game, and each second there is a 10% probability a tree will spawn. Now I want to give the user an output for ten seconds.

Of course, the chances are there will be one tree but there could be anything between 0 and 10 trees - is there any way to generate this without simply rolling a ten sided dice ten times, perhaps all as one calculation my program can run?

Comment: If you're looking for programming advice, you should post on StackOverflow, or any programming forum.

Comment: if I understand you, you have an event with a probability of success of $p=.1$.  You observe this event on $10$ independent occasions and you want the probability that you get no successes, exactly one success, and so on.  Yes?  If so, this is a straight forward application of the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: @lulu This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This helped me greatly:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/23561551/5012509

Binomial distribution is the area of maths relating specifically, where you find a probability based on a distribution of repeated events which do not affect each other.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @lulu :-)